# Add class to cell with PHP to HTML table of MySQL data

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

The following PHP script is pulling data from a MySQL database and displaying the results in a HTML table.

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($currentConfig['host'], $currentConfig['user'], $currentConfig['pass'],
                   $currentConfig['name']);
// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die('Connection failed: '.$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Client, EstimateNumber, Status, TotalEstimatedTime, CostToDateRoleTotal, " .
       "ROUND((CostToDateRoleTotal / TotalEstimatedTime) * 100) AS PercentComplete " .
       "FROM Estimates " .
       "WHERE Status != 'Invoiced' AND Status != 'Cancelled' AND TotalEstimatedTime > 0 " .
       "AND CostToDateRoleTotal > 0 ORDER BY PercentComplete DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $client = $row['Client'];
    $estimate_number = $row['EstimateNumber'];
    $status = $row['Status'];
    $total_estimated_time = $row['TotalEstimatedTime'];
    $role_total = $row['CostToDateRoleTotal'];
    $percent_complete = $row['PercentComplete'];

    // echo data into HTML table
    echo '<tbody>'.'<tr>'.'<td>'.$client.'</td>'.'<td>'.$estimate_number.'</td>'.'<td>'.
         $status.'</td>'.'<td>'.$total_estimated_time.'</td>'.'<td>'.$role_total.'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$percent_complete.' %'.'</td>'.'</tr>'.'</tbody>';
  }
} else {
  echo 'No results';
}
$conn->close();
```

I want to add a `<span>` class to the `<td>` that outputs the `$percent_complete` values if the values in that cell are greater than 50. Both data types that are doing the calculation to create that row's data are DECIMAL. I tried to do the following:

```
  // echo flagged class to span element in table for percent complete
  if ( $percent_complete > 50 ) echo $flag = '<span class="flagged">';
  else echo '<span>';
```

And I edited the HTML table's echo statement to be:

```
  // echo data into HTML table
  echo
  '<tbody>'.'<tr>'.'<td>'.$client.'</td>'.'<td>'.$estimate_number.'</td>'.'<td>'.$status.'</td>'.'<td>'.$total_estimated_time.'</td>'.'<td>'.$role_total.'</td>'.'<td>'.$flag.$percent_complete.' %'.'</span>'.'</td>'.'</tr>'.'</tbody>';
```

However, this adds a `<span class="flagged">` to every row. A `var_dump()` of `$percent_complete` gives me:

```
string(4) "1838"
string(4) "1591"
string(3) "592"
string(3) "416"
string(3) "367"
string(3) "346"
string(3) "305"
string(3) "267"
string(3) "266"
string(3) "231"
string(3) "193"
string(3) "169"
string(3) "157"
string(3) "149"
string(3) "142"
string(3) "136"
string(3) "134"
string(3) "127"
string(3) "114"
string(3) "109"
string(3) "106"
string(3) "103"
string(2) "96"
string(2) "88"
string(2) "71"
string(2) "71"
string(2) "70"
string(2) "67"
string(2) "59"
string(2) "58"
string(2) "46"
string(2) "44"
string(2) "38"
string(2) "38"
string(2) "37"
string(2) "34"
string(2) "18"
string(2) "16"
string(1) "9"
string(1) "4""
```

These are the string values of all of the rows in my table. How do I change my previous if statement to test against each of these string values separately? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic doesn't hold, because you define the `$flag` variable once if `$percent_complete > 50`, but never define it back to an empty string when it's not. So its value is *always* `<span class="flagged">` in every subsequent iteration thereafter.

This code

```
if ( $percent_complete > 50 ) echo $flag = '<span class="flagged">';
else echo '<span>';
```

should be

```
if ( $percent_complete > 50 ) {
    $flag = '<span class="flagged">';
} else {
    $flag = '<span>';
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. You have a small typo - `$flat` should be `$flag`. Thank you!